# Fix my Farseer collision detection code

Tags: xna, farseer-physics-engine

The collision is not working correctly! The collision is in the "open-word" and not when it collides! Here my code:

Platform code(static):

```
body = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, (float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(textureplattform.Width), (float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(textureplattform.Height),1f);
body.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
body.Position = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(Position.X) + textureplattform.Width/2,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(Position.Y) + textureplattform.Height/2);
```

Player code(dynamic):

```
body = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world,(float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(playertexture.Width), (float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(playertexture.Height), 1f);
body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
body.Position = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.X), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.Y));
body.Mass = 1f;
```

Player draw:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
 spriteBatch.Draw(playertexture, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position),null,Color.White, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Rotation), new Vector2(playertexture.Width / 2, playertexture.Height / 2), 1f,SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
```

Platform draw:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
 spriteBatch.Draw(textureplattform, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position), colorplat);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in you *drawing* code, not in the collision code. So the objects are colliding correctly, but you're drawing them in the wrong place.

Looking at your draw code I notice two anomalies:

1. You forgot to draw with the `origin` set to the center of the sprite when drawing the platform. This is mandatory because `Body.Position` refers to the center of mass of the object, which on a rectangular sprite, is at the center. You already seem to be doing this for the player so I won't bother repeating how it's done.
2. When drawing the player, or any other sprite for that matter, you *shouldn't* convert the `rotation` to display units. Angles don't change no matter what the scale is. You only need to convert positions and widths/heights.

To make things easier, I would recommend writing an helper method for drawing physics bodies.  Then reuse this method in every class that needs to draw a body:

```
public static void DrawBody(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture, Body body, Color color)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, 
                     ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position), 
                     null, 
                     color, 
                     body.Rotation,
                     new Vector2(texture.Width / 2f, texture.Height / 2f),
                     1f, 
                     SpriteEffects.None,
                     0f);
}
```

PS: Where you're setting `body.Position` for the platform, you should apply `ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits` to width/2 and height/2 too, if you want it to behave as you expect.